# Insert into a different column using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to select on a table, then use a Case statement to populate the results into a different column?  I've seen an example of using 'Case' to query but not insert into a new column.  I've tried various combinations but coming up short.

For example,

```
    Table - CLIENTDETAILS

    VATRATE - 1, 2, 3, 0  //This is a populated column with 6500 rows

    VATPERC - 15.0, 17.5, 20.0, 0.00  //This is an empty column that needs to be filled with case results.

    INSERT INTO CLIENTDETAILS(VATPERC) values(
    (SELECT CASE VATRATE
      WHEN '1' THEN '15.0'
      WHEN '2' THEN '17.5'
      WHEN '3' THEN '20.0'
      WHEN '0' THEN '0.00'
    END
    FROM CLIENTDETAILS AS CLIENTDETAILS_1))
```

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Don't you really want an `update`?

Comment: Why do you need to *store* these values against every row? Can you not just have a lookup table (with `VATRATE` and `VATPERC`) where you look up these values as required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to update a different column from existing rows

```
UPDATE CLIENTDETAILS
   SET VATPERC = 
     CASE VATRATE
        WHEN '1' THEN '15.0'
        WHEN '2' THEN '17.5'
        WHEN '3' THEN '20.0'
        WHEN '0' THEN '0.00'
      END
  FROM CLIENTDETAILS;
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3ffb/1)

I would suggest however changing the type of `VATRATE` and `VATPERC` to a numeric types, which will allow calculations to be done without casting.

Comment: I'd suggest that `VATPERC` ought to be a computed column or a separate table with this mapping.

Comment: Yes, +1, it seems there is no additional information to be had from this new column (unless it is denormalized for performance, e.g. a readstore)

Comment: Wow of course its an update, I've been looking at this one to long.  Thanks for this Stuart.  The vatrate column and vatperc are numeric types, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Case statement can be used as follows for your need:

```
   INSERT INTO CLIENTDETAILS(VATPERC)
   SELECT 
     CASE 
       WHEN VATRATE = '1' THEN '15.0'
       WHEN VATRATE = '2' THEN '17.5'
       WHEN VATRATE = '3' THEN '20.0'
       WHEN VATRATE ='0' THEN '0.00'
     END
   FROM 
     CLIENTDETAILS
```